# How can I get the session variable that is already being set during ajax call in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

//this is the ajax call that sets the session variable calles sport_id.

```
public function searchAthlete(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $id = $request->id;
            Session::put('sport_id',$id);
            return response()->json(Session::get('sport_id'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you just don't send `['id' => $id]` instead in json() ?

Comment: thanks and will try that

Comment: Actually, I wanted to set the session during ajax call so, that i can use it later. I was just checking whether I can actually set the session during ajax call and I was returning Session::get('sport_id') to verify whether the session is set or not.

Comment: Then do something like `['id' => Session::get('sport_id')]` in json()